# Power BI custom visual - Retrieve filtered data after using applyJsonFilter() method

Tags: typescript, powerbi

Given a native table visual in Power BI, when a row is clicked, the data in the visual is filtered and the filtered data can retrieved via the API with a path through the `options` object similar to

```
const values = options.dataViews[0]['categorical']['categories'][0]['values']
```

However, when the table is filtered using `applyJsonFilter`, the data is returned elsewhere and the `values` array above has no relation to the filter that has been applied.

```js
//filter setup
this.basicFilter = {
  $schema:  'https://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic',
  target: {
      table: 'my_table',
      column: 'my_column'
  },
  operator: "In",
  values:  ['my_value'],
  filterType: FilterType.Basic
}

//apply the filter
this.host.applyJsonFilter(this.basicFilter, "general", "filter", powerbi.FilterAction.merge)
```

The filter is successfully applied, returning a single row:

[image]

But the `dataView` values array, and the underlying table remain unfiltered.

[image]

How do I retrieve the filtered row after using `applyJsonFilter`?

Comment: Hi, have you checked `dataViews[0].table.rows`?

Comment: Hi, I did. That is also unfiltered (shown here by the `identity` key in the table objects).

Answer (score 1):

As per [this Power BI community post](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Custom-Visuals-Development/Apply-JSON-Filter-not-working/m-p/797498#M2581), the "filter" argument in the `applyJsonFilter` method filters all visuals *except* the current one.

To filter the current visual, `"selfFilter"` must be used instead.

```
this.host.applyJsonFilter(null, "general", "selfFilter", powerbi.FilterAction.merge)
```

`"selfFilter"` is undocumented so it is not an obvious fix.

Comment: oh right! Also need to add "selfFilter" property to capabilities.json, Check out this link - https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Custom-Visuals-Development/Apply-JSON-Filter-to-own-custom-visual/m-p/859826